# If derivative of a function is non-zero then it is monotone. Since function is monotone, variable can be substituted in integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I came across this in the text *Differential Equations-An Introduction With Applications*, by Lothar Collatz:

$y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and $g(y)$ is continuous in $[c,d]$. We integrate both sides of the equation

$g(y)y'=f(x)$

with respect to $x$ from a chosen point $x_0$ up to a variable point $x$ (both points are to lie in $[a,b]$), and on the left we introduce $y$ as a new variable instead of $x$ (this is possible if $y'(x)\neq 0$, since then $y(x)$ is monotone in $[x_0,x]$)

Could somebody please explain the last statement?

EDIT: I had not included thought about this earlier but what does monotonicity have anything to do with substitution of a variable in integration.

Comment: This is obviously not a very good book. If a differentiable function has a non-zero derivative then its derivative must always be negative or must always be positive. Since derivatives give the rate of change, the function must always be decreasing or must always be increasing. That is, to me at least, the definition of a monotonic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continuous and $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ then (by the intermediate values theorem) either $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. As a consequence $f$ is monotone.

Comment: But what does monotonicity have to do with making the substitution?

Comment: If you change the question, you cannot hope the answer remains valid. I